# Thread Synchronization can't work

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

i need help, i try to use synchronization thread in java but it can't run...

i have two class with thread like this

```
for(int j=0;j<idW.length;j++){
            webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]); 
            ThreadPrepo tpo =new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j%jumhost], "server", 1099,idW[j]);  
            Thread t1=new Thread(tpo);
            t1.start();
        }
        //thread untuk setfitur tanpa rmi
        int ukuran=idW.length;
        ProsesSetfitur pro=new ProsesSetfitur(idW);
        Thread t2=new Thread(pro);
        t2.start();
```

this is the code in class threadprepo :

```
public class ThreadPrepo implements Runnable{
    String host,server,c,webtext;
    int port,idweb;
    DataDB db=new DataDB();
    public  ThreadPrepo(String webtext,String host,String server,int port,int idweb){
        this.webtext=webtext;
        this.host=host;
        this.server=server;
        this.port=port;
        this.idweb=idweb;    
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
       preponi();
    }

    public synchronized void preponi(){
        try{
           System.out.println("hostnya :"+host);
            Registry reg=LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host,port);
            Sportrmijob rmi=(Sportrmijob) reg.lookup("server");
            rmi.SetInput(webtext);
            List l=rmi.getresult();
            String[] hasilprep=new String[l.size()];
            for(int k=0;k<l.size();k++){
                hasilprep[k]=l.get(k).toString();          
           }
           db.insertWordney(idweb, hasilprep);       
           String [][] frekdb=db.getFrekDB(idweb);
           db.doinsertfrek(idweb,frekdb);

    }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error di class threadprepo "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

and then this is code in class prosesSetFitur

```
public class ProsesSetfitur implements Runnable{
    DataDB d=new DataDB();
    int []idweb;

    public ProsesSetfitur(int[]idweb){  
        this.idweb=idweb;
   }

    @Override
      public void run(){
      try{
          Thread.sleep(500);
          setfitur();
      }
      catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("error setfitur "+e.getMessage());        
       }
    }
    public synchronized void setfitur() throws InterruptedException{     

       System.out.println("(proses setfitur)");  
       String []allkata;
       String fitur;
       String []fiturs=new String[15];
       String []kata_kata=new String[15];
        System.out.println("nilai iD="+idweb.length);
       for(int s=0;s<idweb.length;s++){
            //System.out.println("IDWEEEEEEEEEEB"+idweb[s]);
            allkata=d.getUrutanKata(idweb[s]);  
            for(int u=0;u<15;u++){
               // System.out.println("PERULANGAN U KE"+u);
                if(u<=4){
                    fitur="T";
                    //System.out.println("kata ke" +u+" = "+allkata[u]+" fiturnya = "+fitur);
                    kata_kata[u]=allkata[u];
                    fiturs[u]=fitur;
                }
                else if(u>4&&u<10){
                    fitur="S";
                    //System.out.println("kata ke"+u+" = "+allkata[u]+" fiturnya = "+fitur); 
                    kata_kata[u]=allkata[u];
                    fiturs[u]=fitur;
                }
                else if(u>=10&&u<15){
                   fitur="R" ;
                   //System.out.println("kata ke"+u+" = "+allkata[u]+" fiturnya = "+fitur); 
                   kata_kata[u]=allkata[u];
                   fiturs[u]=fitur;
                }
            }
            d.insertfitur(idweb[s], kata_kata, fiturs);
      } 
      }
```

can anyone give me solution to solve this problem...why thread in class ProsesSetFitur is execute first?how synchronization thread can work?please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void run(){
      try{
          Thread.sleep(500);
          setfitur();
      }
```

> run() method called only once when you start a thread. Again for different thread run() method will be different and call only once for the thread.

Also your preponi() and setfitur() called single time from run(). thats why you should not put synchronized modifier before preponi() and setfitur().

> you should use synchronized when multiple thread access same resource or same function or same code block to make it thread safe.

```
       Thread []tArray=new Thread[idW.length];

        for(int j=0;j<idW.length;j++)
        {
            webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]); 
            ThreadPrepo tpo =new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j%jumhost], "server",     1099,idW[j]);  
            tArray[j]=new Thread(tpo);
            tArray[j].start();
            tArray[j].join();
        }

        //thread untuk setfitur tanpa rmi
        int ukuran=idW.length;
        ProsesSetfitur pro=new ProsesSetfitur(idW);
        Thread t2=new Thread(pro);
        t2.start();
```

Comment: ok...thank u @java seeker for your answer..  i become more understand...
do you have solution to solve this problem so the thread in class ThreadPrepo can first execute and then thread in class ProsesSetFitur is executed after that?

Comment: ...i have try to delete modifier synchronized in preponi() and setfitur() but still  thread in class ProsesSetFitur is executed first...please help me T^T...

Answer (score 0):

A thread sleep may be a pragmatic solution but it is not a guarantee for thread synchronization. To coordinate thread actions you should go for the basic wait/notify pattern whereas the threads uses conditions to perform certain actions. For a good introduction read this articles.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html
http://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example

Comment: thanks @Robert for your refrence dokumen...i will try to learn the refrency....thanks for your help